# Properties of groups related to the existence of group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $f: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and every element of $H$ and of $\operatorname{ker}(f)$ is of finite order, then also every element of $G$ is of finite order.

Comment: What have you tried? Remember that $G/\rm{ker}(f)$ is isomorphic to the image of $f$.

Comment: Yes we tried that we have tried everything and we are a little bit desperated, we tried to prove it with the first isomorphism theorem, but we dont know of H and Ker(f) are finite, because only their elements have finite order

Comment: If $g$ is an element in $G$, do you see that there is some $n$ such that $g^n\in \rm{ker}(f)$? Do you see how to show it from there?

Answer (score 1):

General lemma:

**Lemma:** If $\;G\;$ is a group and $\;N\lhd G\;$ is s.t. $\;[G:N]=k\;$, then for all $\;x\in G\;$ we have that $\;x^k\in N$

**Proof:** Look at the group $\;G/N\;$ . It has order $\;k\;$ so by Lagrange's Theorem any element raised to the group's order equals the identity. But an element in this factor group is of the form $\;xN\;,\;\;x\in G\;$ , and its identity is $\;N\;$ , so the last part says that

$$(xN)^k:=x^kN=N\iff x^k\in N\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\square$$

Well, now in your problem just remember that $\;\ker f\lhd G\;$ , and now apply the above and the given info in the problem.

**Added:** Please do read carefully the comment below this answer by Tobias: it's important!

Comment: The question does not specify that the quotient has finite order, only that all elements of it do (though the same argument can be used).

Comment: You are right, @TobiasKildetoft: I completely missed that piece of info. But with this explanation  a very similar argument as above applies. Thanks, I shall add an edit.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft we have now that (g^n)^m = e but how do we prove that this is the same as g^nm= e , thank you for the fast reactions!

Comment: In any group it always applies the exponents' rule $\;(x^n)^m=x^{nm}\;$ .  A simple inductive argument solves this.

Comment: @heinz that really ought to be a well-known rule about exponents.